# Как установить цвет

Tags: color, android, java, lib

Как я могу установить цвет в диаграмме `mpandroid chart. https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart
Пробую так

```
PieChart mChart; 
...

mChart.setValueTextColor(16777216);
```

Но цвет становится прозрачный или его просто нету, подставлял разные числа. По умолчанию она белая, а надо черный цвет. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, как-то так:

```
 mChart.setValueTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

Comment: спасибо, знаете ли вы эту библиотеку, как там можно круговую диаграмму крутить, то есть если я кручу список она тоже крутилась

Comment: нет. я с этой библиотекой не пользовался, просто знаю о ней :)